# What does "сушить сухари" mean?

Tags: выбор-слова

I tried to google it, but all I got is culinary recipes.
What does "сушить сухари" mean?

---

If a russian person says something like I should "сушить сухари" and it's clearly not about food, what could it mean?
Does it refer to a joke?
Perhaps a popular movie?
Perhaps a kid's cartoon?
Or an adult cartoon?
Or a political incident?
Perhaps it is an expression?
If it's an expresison what does it mean?

I tried to google "сушить сухари" but all I got is recipes about making bisquits
look, like this - 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8

and this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYZWQ1ret_Q

is this indeed only about food (bisquits) and doesn't have another meaning?

Comment: Please provide quote where you've encountered this particular phrase. This will help other to give a proper and more relevant answer.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8

Comment: @SergeySlepov is it about PRISON? OMG ok

Comment: Yes, it's a common expression meaning "get ready to go to prison". **Сухари** (dried bread, croutons) is a food that won't go stale for years, something to eat while your doing time.

Comment: While this expression can be used in its literal sense, 'to dry bread', 'make croutons'.

Comment: @pillarsOE all I've asked about is a quote with example of usage - asking "when it's not about food" is not enough. Please, provide some context - if you are asking about the phrase it means you've happened to see that phrase. Under what exactly circumstances? Why you think that there're other meanings?

Comment: @shabunc while specific example would be nice to have, "суши сухари" has a single well-known idiomatic meaning, and that's "Get ready for prison". So I, personally, tend to disagree with the "unclear" label.

Comment: @IvanMilyakov it's obvious for as as native speakers, it's not so obvious for one who just learning Russian. Also it will set a precedent where we are telling apart question where it's sort of obvious from where we still need the quote.

Comment: @shabunc I do agree with Ivan Milyakov and would recommend to remove the "on hold" mark from this good question.